# How can I create an ISO image from a dvd with my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, dvd, iso-image, images

I can only create an cdr image, but not iso. Is it possible to create an iso image using mac standard software (disk utility)?

Regards Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'cdr' files match the ISO spec.  So once you create the image you can safely rename the file to .iso and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder of the stuff you want to put in the image.

Launch Disk Utility and choose

> File -> New -> Disk Image From Folder

In the "Select Folder to Image" dialog box select your folder and click `Image`. In the resulting "New Image From Folder" dialog box choose `DVD/CD Master` and `None` from the Encryption pop-up menu.

Save the image to the Desktop.

Open Terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop

hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o Test.iso Test.cdr
```